# Prefixo em node restify

Tags: node.js, restify

Tenho meu módulo no nodejs e gostaria de ter um prefixo para não precisar repetir toda vez o início:

Por exemplo, no arquivo **route.js**

```
const db = require('../services')
const routes = (server) => {
    server.get('/v1', (req, res, next) => {
        res.send('Engoy the silence')
        next()
    })

    server.get('/v1/beers', async (req, res, next) => {
        try{
            res.send( await db.beers().all() )
        }catch(error){
            res.send(error)
        }
        next()
    })
}
module.exports = routes
```

Gostaria de configurar um prefixo antes no meu **index.js**. Tentei assim:

```
server.use('/api', function(req, res, next){

})

routes(server)
```

Mas não sei mais o que fazer rsrs

Como crio um prefixo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos, uma sugestão seria exportar os routes e configurá-los no server.js (arquivo de configuração do seu projeto). Fiz isso utilizando o Express, segue a ideia:

```
// allows receive all request types
userRoute = require('./src/routes/userRoute');
teamRoute = require('./src/routes/teamRoute');
projectRoute = require('./src/routes/projectRoute');

routes = [
    userRoute,
    teamRoute,
    projectRoute,
];


app.use('/api/v1', ...routes);
```

Dessa forma, todos os endpoins dos routes começarão com '/api/v1' + o endereço endpoint do route que você configurou.